# this.$socket undefined with vue-native-websocket and vue-socket.io in vue typescript application

Tags: typescript, vue.js, websocket

I use Vue Typescript and I want to use WebSocket in my application. I tried `view-native-websocket` and `view-socket.io` and I am confused with the same problems with both packages.

First, they do not seem to be compatible typescript. (The compiler displays the message: "Could not find a declaration file for module 'vue-...")

But the main problem is that in the Vue components `this.$socket` is undefined, like `this.$connection` or `this.$options.socket`, although I added the Vue.use statement below in the main.ts as shown in the documentation.

> `import VueNativeSock from 'vue-native-websocket'
>   Vue.use(VueNativeSock,'ws://localhost:8999')`;

Can someone explain to me why?

Comment: Did you ever figure out why this wasn't working? I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found that accessing it this way works: `Vue.prototype.$socket`